# Alamofire crash only in device

Tags: ios, alamofire

I'm using Alamofire.download to get my image file. It runs fine in simulator, but crashes in device.

Below is my download function

```
func downImage(url : String, success: (image: UIImage?)-> Void, failure: ()-> Void)
{
    if let image = self.cacheImage(url.lastPathComponent)
    {
        success(image: image)
    }else
    {
        let destination = Alamofire.Request.suggestedDownloadDestination(directory: .DocumentDirectory, domain: .UserDomainMask)
        Alamofire.download(.GET, url, destination: destination)
            .progress { bytesRead, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead in
                println(totalBytesRead)

                log.debug("\(totalBytesRead)/\(totalBytesExpectedToRead)")
            }
            .response { (request, response, responseData, error) -> Void in

                if response?.statusCode == 200
                {

                    if let image = self.cacheImage(response?.suggestedFilename)
                    {
                        success(image: image)
                    }else
                    {
                        success(image: nil)
                    }


                }else
                {
                    failure()
                }

        }
    }
}
```

And the crash happens in Request.swift.

```
/**
    Resumes the request.
*/
public func resume() {
    task.resume()
}
```

And crash message is

> EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: I too ran into this - did you resolve?

Comment: @aehlke I checked former project. I used UIImageView+AFNetworking.h instead.

Comment: All I had to do was clear derived data, in the end.